# How to get access token to create a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to create a list with javascript.

From the Sharepoint API Documentation:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists
method: "POST",
body: { 
 '__metadata': { 
   'type': 'SP.List' 
 }, 
 'AllowContentTypes': true, 
 'BaseTemplate': 100,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
 'Description': 'My list description', 
 'Title': 'Test' 
},
Headers: 
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
X-RequestDigest: form digest value
accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
content-length:length of post body
```

Right now I'm receiving :
*Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content.*

My guess is that I'm not sending the **Authorization** header.

**The problem:**

Where can I get the accessToken value ??

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mysiteurl/sites/Processos/_api/web/lists', 
    data: { 
      '__metadata': { 
        'type': 'SP.List' 
      }, 
      'AllowContentTypes': true, 
      'BaseTemplate': 100,
      'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 
      'Description': 'My descrição de lista', 
      'Title': 'ListaCriadaTest' 
    },
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": digest, 
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // ...
    },
    error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
      // ...
    }
});
```

The GET requests works fine without accessToken, but now I need to create lists, so I need to do POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need access token only in case if you are outside of SharePoint. For example, SharePoint provider hosted add-in, or a separate web site, which uses Azure AD authentication.

As GET works for you just fine, I assume you are in a context of SharePoint site. In other words, you run your script from SharePoint site. In that case you don't need an access token, because you have already authenticated.
The one thing is required for POST though. That's `X-RequestDigest`, which you provided.

One another thing I noticed that you use non-Latin symbols in description and list title. Try to change that and check if it works. If works, then try to encode this value with `encodeURIComponent` method and check again.

**UPD**
You should also stringify you data, i.e. `data: JSON.stringify({'metadata: ...})`

Comment: Thanks for answering, Sergei . Yes, it's in a context of Sharepoint. I changed the symbols, and still not working. Same error.

Comment: You should also stringify you data, i.e. `data: JSON.stringify({'metadata: ...})`. I've noticed you haven't done that.

Comment: Perfect, worked after stringify ! Thank you very much !